# How do you import Firebase Auth, Firestore and Firebase Storage node packages as well as their TypeScript's types in a class?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I need to import Firebase packages and get them into a class for a module that has to be compatible with both Next.js and React Native. This works pretty well for the React Native version but I'm less used to React with TypeScrit and encounter serveral issues.

Setup:

- VS Code
- TypeScript 3.9
- TSLint 5
- Lerna multirepo + Yarn workspaces with :
- a @project/apps common package (we are here)
- a @project/web package with next.js using this file
- a @project/mobile package for React native, using the .native.ts version of this file

Here is the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts", "**/__tests__/*", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"]
}
```

here is the tslint.json:

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-config-prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "interface-name": false,
    "member-access": [true, "no-public"],
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "no-console": false
  }
}
```

Here is the code of the Firebase class:

```js
import app from '@firebase/app'
import { FirebaseApp } from '@firebase/app-types'
import '@firebase/firestore'
import { FirebaseFirestore } from '@firebase/firestore-types'
import '@firebase/auth'
import { FirebaseAuth } from '@firebase/auth-types'
import '@firebase/storage'
import { FirebaseStorage } from '@firebase/storage-types'

import firebaseConfig from './config'

export class Firebase {
  app: FirebaseApp
  auth: FirebaseAuth
  db: FirebaseFirestore
  firestore: FirebaseFirestore
  files: FirebaseStorage

  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    this.app = app.app()
    this.auth = app.auth()
    this.db = app.firestore()
    this.firestore = app.firestore
    this.files = app.storage()
  }
}

const firebase = new Firebase()
export default firebase
```

I have serveral issues :

On @firebase/firestore import:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '@firebase/firestore'. 'c:/code/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/firebase__firestore` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@firebase/firestore';`ts(7016)
```

on this.auth = app.auth() and this.files = app.storage()

```
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)
```

on this.db = app.firestore() and this.firestore = app.firestore

```
Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'FirebaseNamespace'.ts(2339)
```

Ok... It is a mess. I read several tutorials but I don't get it from now. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use TypeScript for Firebase, I don't use any packages that start with "@".  Everything can be imported just fine, as illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize).  From that page:

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics
import "firebase/analytics";

// Add the Firebase products that you want to use
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for your answer. This gives me this type of errors when I type "yarn":

Error: Couldn't find package "firebase/auth@^0.14.9" required by "@project/apps@0.0.10" on the "npm" registry.

Comment: "Lerna add" error is quite strande too: lerna ERR! Error: Invalid package name "firebase/app-types": name can only contain URL-friendly characters
lerna ERR!     at invalidPackageName (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\lerna\node_modules\npm-package-arg\npa.js:86:15)

Comment: I don't know about yarn.  I use npm to install modules.

Comment: Well, i'm not sure that it is the source of the problem. I've been using the @ for all modules with author/module name so far without an issue.

Comment: Well, appart this @ i guess that your answer mean that you don't see a specific issue. So maybe it is just weird typescript errors. I will see once I will be able to launch the app. Thanks.

Comment: It's not that I don't see a problem.  It's that I see (and use) an alternative that's covered by documentation.

Comment: I will ask a specific question about this @ issue to see if someone understand this and what are the differences.

Comment: Ok, so for follow-up, I discovered that using '@namespace/packageName' import the package "packageName" from @namespace while using 'package/partName' is meant to import only a part of package. Firebase uses 'package/partName' for partial imports for users and '@namespace/packageName' for internal development. So you were right to point this out. I will post the new code in an answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the new code, following the discussions in Doug's answer:

```js
import app from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'

import firebaseConfig from './config'

export class Firebase {
  app: app.app.App
  auth: app.auth.Auth
  db: app.firestore.Firestore
  firestore: (app?: app.app.App | undefined) => app.firestore.Firestore
  files: app.storage.Storage

  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    this.app = app.app()
    this.auth = app.auth()
    this.db = app.firestore()
    this.firestore = app.firestore
    this.files = app.storage()
  }
}

const firebase = new Firebase()
export default firebase
```

There is not errors this time.

Comment: based on your answer I'm getting this error `Namespace '"c:/Users/username/OneDrive/Documents/React/quick-refactor/likeme/node_modules/firebase/app/dist/app/index"' has no exported member 'app'`

Comment: Hi, what line? It is possible that some things have changed.