# Difference between import 'namespace/module' and import '@namespace/module' with TypeScript and Yarn?

Tags: typescript, firebase, npm, yarnpkg, lerna

On [an unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586507/how-do-you-import-firebase-auth-firestore-and-firebase-storage-node-packages-as/63586941) we are wondering with Doug, from Google Firebase support, if the different ways of importing packages could be a source of bugs.

The documentation tells to do like this, with Typescript and npm:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
```

I use Yarn and Lerna, with Typescript 3.9. It requires me to add a @ at the beginning of imports using the namespace/module syntaxe, otherwise it complains about not url friendly characters.

I use:

```
import firebase from "@firebase/app";
import "@firebase/auth";
import "@firebase/firestore";
```

Are the 2 options actually different in such a way that the second one could trigger bugs that would not happen in the first one, just because of this @ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two different import paths mean two different things:

1. `import "@firebase/auth"` means that you are importing the `@firebase/auth` NPM package. This means that the package itself is published in NPM as `@firebase/auth`
2. `import "firebase/auth"` means that you are importing the `auth` folder from the `firebase` package

Looking at the [`@firebase/auth`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/auth) readme it says

> This package is not intended for direct usage, and should only be used via the officially supported [firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) package.

That seems to support the docs that you should be using the `firebase` package and importing one of its subfolders.

Re your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586507/how-do-you-import-firebase-auth-firestore-and-firebase-storage-node-packages-as/63586941): which package did you actually `npm install`?

Because if you are using the `firebase` package *that* is what you should have installed, not `firebase/auth` - which is not its own NPM module - or `@firebase/auth` which is not meant for direct use.

If you did install `@firebase/auth` that would explain why TypeScript can't find the types in the `firebase/auth` path as that's not the same package you installed.